# I get this error when I run the following code : '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, scipy

```
time_periods = [
    'One-Year',
    'Six-month',
    'Three-month',
    'One-month']

for row in hqm_dataframe.index:

    for time_period in time_periods:

         hqm_dataframe.loc[row,f'{time_period} return percentile'] = stats.percentileofscore(hqm_dataframe[f'{time_period} price return'], hqm_dataframe.loc[row,f'{time_period} price return'])
```

If someone has a possible solution then it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hi so I found a solution to this. As I am still relatively new to this I made a noob mistake of not taking null values into account as I was following a tutorial from freecodecamp.